# How to display buttons in the views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I am known Drupal 8.7 and Bootstrap 3.4.1

To reproduce the problem :

- Create a view.
- Add a "Global: Text area" header.
- Check the "Use replacement tokens from the first row" case.
- Add the following code :

  ```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-cgv" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-cgv">
    Conditions générales de vente
  </button>
  ```

The button does not appear, there is only the text.

If the box "Use replacement tokens from the first row" is not hidden, the buttons work months tokens no longer work.

Why buttons do not work with views ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding "Text area" add "Unfiltered text" and drupal won't strip your tags from it.

But if you prefer "Text area" you should select different "Text format" (drop down just bellow text area where you edit the content. You can edit those text formats your self, specify what tags should be stripped and what will stay. For start try replacing "Basic html" text format with "Full html" format.

Check out screenshots:

https://paste.pics/11d36665dc8bbfca341755951e53e78c

https://paste.pics/9837e65da7e5aa3976d6c1997a58098f

Comment: Hi, with "Unfiltered text" it does not work, the result is the same

Comment: With text format set like that html tags should not be stripped

Comment: Just tried on my (local) site. Selected "Global: text area", text format "Full html", pasted your code and button is displayed well.

Comment: So I do not understand. Can you test my code in a view ?

Comment: Tested and uploaded screenshots, check out update on my replay above.

Comment: Ok they work too, but if you check the box "Use replacement tokens from the first row" buttons do not work anymore.

Comment: Tried [site:name]  token and works fine for me. Button is still there

Comment: You tick the box?

Comment: Ok so you have the same problem ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not using that option at all? What token do you need from the first row?

Comment: You could add another, block display to that view, limit it to display only one row and then include that block as a header of you problematic display. Some kind of workaround...

Comment: I would like to put this code in the product template of "Drupal Commerce". But I do not know how to make this condition with TWIG: If the parent store is of a professional type.

Comment: In "Global: custom text" there is no <button> tag it's very weird. https://ibb.co/pvzQd0c

Comment: It's filtered out...the question is - why?

Comment: is it possible to rewrite the view with a TWIG template and use the view tokens in the templates ?

Comment: The buttons work very well with TWIG. Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976083/how-to-retrieve-information-from-the-parent-store-of-a-product